# Windows Phone 8 MediaStreamSource with multiple audio streams

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8, stream, mediastreamsource

I have MediaStreamSource implementation which can open files with multiple audio streams. In OpenMediaAsync method i deliver MediaStreamDescription for all video and audio streams but MediaElement detects only 1 audio stream. Also I have tested next logic which works:

- detected 2 streams
- report only first or second MediaStreamDescription of audio stream to ReportOpenMediaCompleted

But of course I want to report first and second audio stream to ReportOpenMediaCompleted and in result have MediaElement with 2 audio streams. Also I have discovered StreamId field inside MediaStreamSource class but it doesn't have set accessor, and when reporting streams with ReportOpenMediaCompleted all MediaStreamDescription have StreamId == 0.

OpenMediaAsync code:

```
protected override void OpenMediaAsync()
{
    this.streamDesc = new Dictionary<int, MediaStreamDescription>();
    List<MediaStreamDescription> availableStreams = new List<MediaStreamDescription>();

    for (int i = 0; i < this.parser.StreamCount; i++)
    {
        Dictionary<MediaStreamAttributeKeys, string> streamAttributes = new Dictionary<MediaStreamAttributeKeys, string>();
        MediaStreamDescription msd = null;

        var type = this.parser.GetStreamType(i);
        streamAttributes[MediaStreamAttributeKeys.CodecPrivateData] = this.parser.GetCodecPrivateData(i);

        if (type == ParserComponent.StreamType.Video)
        {
            streamAttributes[MediaStreamAttributeKeys.VideoFourCC] = this.parser.GetCodecID(i);
            streamAttributes[MediaStreamAttributeKeys.Width] = this.parser.GetWidth(i).ToString();
            streamAttributes[MediaStreamAttributeKeys.Height] = this.parser.GetHeight(i).ToString();

            msd = new MediaStreamDescription(MediaStreamType.Video, streamAttributes);
        }
        else if (type == ParserComponent.StreamType.Audio)
        {
            msd = new MediaStreamDescription(MediaStreamType.Audio, streamAttributes);
        }

        if (msd != null)
        {
            if (i == this.parser.CurrentAudioStreamIndex || i == this.parser.CurrentVideoStreamIndex)
            {
                this.parser.SetStreamActive(i, true);

                // quick fix for multilanguage videos to submit only 1 audio stream
                // availableStreams.Add(msd);
            }

            this.streamDesc.Add(i, msd);
            availableStreams.Add(msd);
            }
        }

        Dictionary<MediaSourceAttributesKeys, string> sourceAttributes = new Dictionary<MediaSourceAttributesKeys, string>();

        sourceAttributes[MediaSourceAttributesKeys.CanSeek] = this.parser.Seekable.ToString();
        sourceAttributes[MediaSourceAttributesKeys.Duration] = this.parser.Duration.Ticks.ToString();

        ReportOpenMediaCompleted(sourceAttributes, availableStreams);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be it's a good idea to use [Player framework](https://playerframework.codeplex.com/). It supports multiple audio streaming.